# Lambda Calculus Evaluation

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I know this is a simple question but can someone show me how
$(\lambda y. \lambda x. \lambda y.y) (\lambda x. \lambda y. y)$ reduces to $\lambda x. \lambda y. y$.

Comment: Are you sure you parenthesized this correctly? Because the way it's written, I don't see how it can be simplified at all. If it was `(λy.λx.λy.y) (λx.λy.y)`, it'd reduce to `λx.λy.y`.

Comment: Yes thanks I updated my question. Could you explain how you got λx.λy.y

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that $(\lambda y. \lambda x. \lambda y.y) (\lambda x. \lambda y. y)$ reduces to $\lambda x. \lambda y. y$ and not to $\lambda x. \lambda y.\lambda x.\lambda y.y$ is that the $y$ in the body of $\lambda y.\lambda x.\lambda y.y$ refers to the argument of the third lambda, not the first.

If you rename the arguments to have distinct names, $\lambda y.\lambda x.\lambda y.y$ would be written as $\lambda y_1.\lambda x.\lambda y_2.y_2$. So if you apply that function to the argument, that means that every occurrence of $y_1$ in $\lambda x.\lambda y_2.y_2$ should be replaced with the argument. However $y_1$ does not appear at all in that expression, so the argument is simply ignored and the result is just $\lambda x.\lambda y_2.y_2$.

Comment: Oh ok so the y2 is not bound to y1. Thank you very much.

Comment: @prerm2686 A variable is always bound by the closest encompassing $\lambda$. The subterm $\lambda y.y$ is the identity function, no matter where you use it, even if you use it in a context that also uses the variable name $y$.

Comment: [Reduction on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction) gives a more formal treatment of α-conversion and β-reduction. A reference I like is [Chris Hankin's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Lambda-Calculi-Computer-Scientists/dp/0954300653)